# Android SQLite SELECT NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm hoping someone can help me as I'm stuck with this error and logs are not helping me! I'm trying to read from my database, which I know contains the table and data as I have extracted it. It seems to have an error with this line:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SORTBY, null);
```

It's strange as I have used this code before but I can't see what I'm doing wrong, anyhelp would be gratefully appreciated.

```
/** Get all locations for the dialog box */
public ArrayList<String> allLocations() {
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SORTBY, null);
    ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SORTBY_SORTBY_TYPE)));
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("All Locations", "Error getting locations: " + e.toString());
    }finally{
        mCursor.close();
        close();
    }
    return mArrayList;
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
08-11 14:18:00.465: E/ERROR(19396): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 14:18:00.465: W/System.err(19396): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 14:18:00.465: W/System.err(19396):    at com.swiftdrink.sqlite.SortBySQL.allLocations(SortBySQL.java:99)
08-11 14:18:00.465: W/System.err(19396):    at com.swiftdrink.SortByList.displaySortByList(SortByList.java:127)
08-11 14:18:00.525: D/dalvikvm(19396): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2629 objects / 147472 bytes in 51ms
08-11 14:18:00.525: W/System.err(19396):    at com.swiftdrink.SortByList.downloadSortBy(SortByList.java:116)
08-11 14:18:00.525: W/System.err(19396):    at com.swiftdrink.SortBy.onCreate(SortBy.java:58)
08-11 14:18:00.525: W/System.err(19396):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-11 14:18:00.525: W/System.err(19396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-11 14:18:00.525: W/System.err(19396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-11 14:18:00.535: W/System.err(19396):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 14:18:00.545: W/System.err(19396):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-11 14:18:00.545: W/System.err(19396):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-11 14:18:00.545: W/System.err(19396):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-11 14:18:00.545: W/System.err(19396):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In case you're wondering this is my whole SQL class.

```
public class SortBySQL {

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String sortby = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SORTBY
            + " (" + SORTBY_SORTBY_ID + " INT," + SORTBY_SORTBY_TYPE + " TEXT " + ");");

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(sortby);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SortBySQL(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public SortBySQL open() throws SQLException {
        this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        this.mDbHelper.close();     
    }

    /** Add to the sort by list */
    public long addSortBy(String sortByID, String sortByType) {
        Log.d("addLocation", "FUCK");

        Log.d("Add Location", sortByID + " " + sortByType);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(SORTBY_SORTBY_ID, sortByID);
        values.put(SORTBY_SORTBY_TYPE, sortByType);

        return this.mDb.insert(TABLE_SORTBY , null, values);
    }

    /** Get all locations for the dialog box */
    public ArrayList<String> allLocations() {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SORTBY, null);
        ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
                mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SORTBY_SORTBY_TYPE)));
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("All Locations", "Error getting locations: " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            mCursor.close();
            close();
        }
        return mArrayList;
    }

    /** Delete all from the location table */
    public void deleteAllSortBy() {
        Log.d("Delete Locations", "Delete Locations");
        mDb.delete(TABLE_SORTBY, null, null);
        close();
    }

    /** Check that there are locations stored */
    public boolean countSortBy() {
        Log.e("countLocation", "countLocation");

        Cursor count = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_SORTBY,
                null);

        if (count == null) {
            return false;
        }
        count.close();
        close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is where you think it is.  What are the four lines referenced in the logcat?  SortBy line 58, SortByList line 116, SortByList line 127 and SortBySQL line 99...

Answer (score 0):

If its a problem with your query (which in this case doesn't really seem), then perhaps try changing it as below:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_SORTBY, null, null, null, null,
        null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are attempting to open a cursor on the sqlite database wich is not opened that 's why it gives you `NullPointerException` try to verify that your database is created and opened before executing any sql command on it.

Answer (score -1):

Context ??

```
final Context context = this;
dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
```

Comment: Could you maybe flesh out your answer with some explanation why and how this bit of code solves OP's problem? As it is now, your answer does not seem to be very useful.